# Visual Studio localization & Forms: asp:button, asp:CheckBox reading default language .resx file only

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, forms, localization

I have localized most of my website, using Visual Studio 2010 (VB)/asp.net 4.0.

It's mostly going well, but I'm trying to localize contactengineering.aspx.  Here, I have two issues:  asp:checkbox and asp:button.  They're not reading the fr, de, and es files -- only the default contactengineering.aspx.resx, which is en.

What I did was created the resource files in VS (tools/generate local resource), which put in a directory for App_LocalResources.  Here's the mystery.  My asp:label didn't translate either.  But I put this fix in:

```
      <h1><asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" 
    Text="<%$ Resources:LocalizedText, contacteng1 %>"></asp:Label></h1>
```

And I put a string for contacteng1 in my **App_GlobalResources** in my root folder, and it localized in all languages.

**Here's the problem**

Similarly, my asp:button and asp:checkbox functions aren't localizing.  They're reading from the default /**App_LocalResources**/contactengineering.aspx.resx.  I tried the "fix" I came up with, moving it to GlobalResources, but it doesn't work.

Here's my code that I'm trying to localize:

```
                  <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBoxCC" runat="server" 
                Text="does not matter what I put here" 
                meta:resourcekey="CheckBoxCCResource1" />
            <br />
            <br />
            <asp:Button ID="SubmitForm" runat="server" OnClick="SubmitForm_Click" 
                Text="Submit Form" meta:resourcekey="SubmitFormResource1" />
```

The entire page is localized except for this button and checkbox. Could anybody tell me what I need to do?  I would sincerely appreciate any help anybody could offer me in this regard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the fix I just found via trial and error -- been working on it for awhile now -- in case anybody has any similar issues.  I don't know if this is proper or (recommended), but it's what worked.

I replaced:

```
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBoxCC" runat="server" 
            Text="does not matter what I put here" 
            meta:resourcekey="CheckBoxCCResource1" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="SubmitForm" runat="server" OnClick="SubmitForm_Click" 
            Text="Submit Form" meta:resourcekey="SubmitFormResource1" />
```

with:

```
                  <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBoxCC" runat="server" 
                Text="<%$ Resources:LocalizedText, contacteng11 %>"></asp:CheckBox>
            <br />
            <br />
            <asp:Button ID="SubmitForm" runat="server" OnClick="SubmitForm_Click" 
                Text="<%$ Resources:LocalizedText, contacteng12 %>"></asp:Button>
```

And I added the strings contacteng11 and contacteng12 and their respective values to each language .resx file in my **App_GlobalResources** directory.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Viual Studio, I fixed the similar problem I had by looking at the website's "Properties Window" and changing the "Localizable" property from "Default" to "Yes".